# Change argv[0] in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

`argv[0]` is the full path of the file with extension in Netbeans, but when the same piece of code is run in Sublime Text it gives output with a forward slash and without a file extension.

```
printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
```

Output in Netbeans:

```
F:\Projects\C\Xnet\Xnet\dist\Debug\MinGW-Windows\StartX.exe
```

Output in Sublime Text:

```
F:\Projects\C\Xnet\Xnet/StartX
```

Why? How to change this in Sublime Text to get the same result as in Netbeans?

Comment: Why not?  Both are valid.  It is up to the code which launches the program to set `argv[0]`.  The only problem is with your expectations.  What you expected isn't unreasonable, but it isn't the way things actually work.

Comment: Why is it a problem? What do you want to do with it? There is no standard for `argv[0]`, only conventions.

Comment: @Boiethios It should be " F:\Projects\C\Xnet\Xnet\StartX " not " F:\Projects\C\Xnet\Xnet/StartX". Why the forward slash before the filename? Is it normal in sublime text ?

Comment: " It should be …" - please provide a reference to the standard. And that is not a matter of C.

Comment: The forward slash looks like a bug to me, it should be a \ in order to be consistent, even if a forward slash is actually not wrong. If it bothers, program  a workaround.

Comment: IMO, the `c` tag is not relevant. The problem is that Sublime Text uses an Unix-like path style in Windows.

Comment: On Windows, you can use either backslash or slash as a path separator in the API calls, and they work the same.  The `cmd.exe` command interpreter and many programs it runs use slash to indicate options, but that's a program decision, not enforced by the Windows API. it is perhaps sloppy to use a slash, but it isn't wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good to know. So it is up to the OP to explain why this is a problem. Maybe this question deserves to be closed.

Comment: @Boiethios After a lot of trial and error, I think i have got some clue. The above problem has something to do with the build system option in sublime text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think I have some clue. I changed the build system option in the sublime text.

```
{
 "cmd" : "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name}",
 "selector" : "source.c",
 "shell" : true,
 "working_dir" : "$file_path",
 "variants":
    [
     {
      "name": "Run",
      "cmd": "${file_base_name}.exe"
     }
   ]
}
```

Now argv[0] returns only filename with extension (filename.exe)

Comment: Do not put clue there, but only full valid answer. It seems that `"cmd"` in `"variants"` is the key of your question: once you find how to modify it to fit your purpose, please post your answer with explanation.

Comment: @Boiethios I dont know how to append '//'  to $file_path. I am not familiar with this...